# Is that possible writing a Swift lib for Android NOW?

Tags: android, swift

We're considering to write a lib for both iOS and Android using Swift instead of C/C++.

I found some talks about Swift on Android:

- [How we put an app in the Android Play Store using Swift](https://medium.com/@ephemer/how-we-put-an-app-in-the-android-play-store-using-swift-67bd99573e3c)
- [#Pragma Conference 2016 - Axel Schlueter - Swift on Android](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2TxbLAX36h0)
- [Swift on Android: The Future of Cross-Platform Programming or White Whale?](https://news.realm.io/news/swift-on-android/)

Comment: you better forget about it and stick to C++. will be less pain. IMHO of course

Answer (score 0):

In MillerTechnologies, we are working on that currently. Look those repos out.

https://github.com/MillerTechnologyPeru/swift-android

https://github.com/PureSwift/Android

We base our project on this repo

https://github.com/SwiftJava/swift-android-kotlin

but firstly you need to configure the toolchain

https://github.com/SwiftJava/android_toolchain